# How to run javascript code from notepad++ to chrome

Tags: javascript

When i run my code in google chrome from notepad++,instead of running the code and typing one message, it writes all my code in the page.How can i fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN>" "w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">; 
<html> <head> </head> <body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write("Message"); </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: The problem is on line 32.

Comment: You cannot just open a javascript file in chrome. It must be embedded in an html document.

Comment: yes my code is embedded with html

Comment: @iEatBacon — It clearly isn't embedded in HTML correctly. Of course, we have no way of telling what you are doing wrong. You haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: Show the code you are working with.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN>"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("Message");
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Transitional in 2018? XHTML 1.0 in 2018? Why?! Your XHTML is invalid anyway. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Also make use of the Edit link to edit the code into your question.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](http://jsbin.com/zehujaqexu/1/edit?html,output) - your [mcve] needs to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Well basically i saw this code on youtube an i just copied that in notepad++,but on youtube the code was working perfectly,but my code doesnt..

Comment: This qualifies as about the poorest question I have ever seen here, because you have not done any research at all, and have not done any proper training at all. You just start with something and the first problem you encounter, you dump on this forum. You will need a million more questions answered that way.

Comment: Ok i fixed the problem thanks to Scott Marcus, thank you for your time and have a nice day

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The very first thing to check is what type of file you saved your document as. It should have an `.html` or `.htm` file extension.

Next, your HTML is not written properly, starting with the `DOCTYPE`, which stands for Document Type and tells the browser what type of document it should process.

You have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN>" "w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">;
```

But, it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

And that's only if you really want to use the XHTML 1.0 Transitional document type, which most-likely you don't since that is an old and rarely used document type these days.

Instead, you'd probably want to use the HTML5 document type, which is just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

After that, the rest of your code is good enough to render in the browser, although it is not actually valid because the `head` section requires a `title` element. Also, it is no longer required to add `type=text/javascript` in your `script` tag. It's essential to understand that browsers just interpret HTML the best they can according to some built-in rules, but they don't provide error messages about invalid HTML. To validate your HTML, you can go to http://validator.w3.org and paste your code into their online validation tool. If you do that with your current code, you will see that it indicates that the document can't even be checked and that's because of the invalid DOCTYPE.

It should look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Some Page Title Here</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <script>
    document.write("Message");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will show the XHTML as plain text if it thinks the file it has been given is a plain text file.

Since you are opening it locally, the file content will be inferred from the file extension.

Presumably, you have given the file a `.txt` file extension instead of a `.html` one.

Be aware that your Windows configuration may hide file extensions from you so you may have tried to save the file as `example.html` but actually saved it as `example.html.txt` with the `.txt` being hidden from view.